# halloween.zip file

Tags: mechanical-puzzles

I found an envelope in my mailbox today. It had some some weird looking symbol where the sender's address should have been, but I decided to open it anyway.

> We've been watching you.  Since you enjoy puzzles, we've taken the liberty of offering you one.  If you check your Google Drive, you'll notice a new file we've added for you.  Enjoy.

Questioning how they would be able to add a file to my drive, I open it up and sure enough, [there is a new file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8vKGnntEl3nMXVpUk1rdEJ3UTA).  It's named `halloween.zip` and has some numbered folders and images that appear to be puzzle pieces.

Can you help figure out what the image they sent me is?

**EDIT**

For those that don't want to download the zip, the images are below.  Each row is from a different folder named 1 through 15.  There is also a 0 folder that contains a single txt file with the text

> `Nothing to see here... Move along, Move along.`

Image of puzzle pieces:

> [image: Pieces]

Comment: hmmm, tempting, but as a programmer I know better than just open a strange unknown zip file ^^;

Comment: I opened it (AVG would tell me if its bad) and its fine

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I fear you may have an excessive amount of trust in your AV package... Admittedly, it would be a strange vector for attack, but there have been stranger ones...

Comment: @stackreader I was going to post the images, but 135 images is quite a bit.  Plus I needed a way to split the pieces and also have the 0 folder.

Comment: Still, posting links to not well defined files is heavily frowned upon on this site. -1 for me.  Also, the tag "mechanical puzzle" doesn't go very well with a .zip file.  (Would jigsaw-puzzle not be better?) If you're just aiming at putting a lot of images in a puzzle, alternatives are better - and an overview image in the puzzle would defenitely be welcomed. I've vote -1 on this question for the moment for these reasons, not actually juding the actual puzzle.

Comment: @DavidStarkey is the 0 folder actually important?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil The folder naming is important and the 0 folder does have meaning.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil I've added a compiled image of all the pieces so it is no longer required to download the zip file.

Comment: @DavidStarkey finished the final image, unsure about file 0 though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we put the pieces 1-15 (shown below) in a $4x4$ grid and slide using 'Nothing to see here' we get the The final image (sorry for putting it together badly) is:

> [image]

File 0 has a text document which says:

> Nothing to see here... Move along, Move along.

The rest are typical jigsaw puzzles.

The pieces in the file called 1 fit together like this:

> [image]

Seems to be a pumpkin navel...

The pieces in the file called 2 fit together like this:

> [image]

The pieces in the file called 3 fit together like this:

> [image]

Clearly part of a pumpkin.

The pieces in the file called 4 fit together like this:

> [image]

The pieces in the file called 5 fit together like this:

> [image]

The pieces in the file called 6 fit together like this:

> [image]

The pieces in the file called 7 fit together like this:

> [image]

The pieces in the file called 8 fit together like this:

> [image]

The pieces in the file called 9 fit together like this:

> [image]

The pieces in the file called 10 fit together like this:

> [image]

The pieces in the file called 11 fit together like this:

> [image]

The pieces in the file called 12 fit together like this:

> [image]

The pieces in the file called 13 fit together like this:

> [image]

The pieces in the file called 14 fit together like this:

> [image]

The pieces in the file called 15 fit together like this:

> [image]

And all of these put together give us a pumpkin shown at the top!

Comment: First picture looks like a naval (like on an orange), but the second picture more resembles a pumpkin (Halloween).

Comment: @jstnthms just finished 3 which is clearly the bottom of a pumpkin

Comment: For putting them together, it might be a slider-type puzzle where 1 goes in the top left then 16 is a blank square at the bottom right. The pieces that then get moved might have some sort of conversion to letters that match image 0?

Comment: @Sconibulus Ive just put them together and I don't think so

Comment: @Sconibulus That was the idea, with the slider-puzzle resulting in the final image.  BeastlyGerbil just kinda bypassed the sliding bit and put them in the final configuration.

Comment: @DavidStarkey oh sorry, do you want me to add that part in? (I'll have to do it in the morning)

Comment: It would be nice for a complete answer